# How to RTL text in Reporting Service Expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression, right-to-left

Working with Reporting Service and RTL Language (Hebrew)

I have an Expression on a column that append some Hebrew text to a number.

The expression look like this:

```
 Format(Fields!sumToAuthorityDiff.Value,"0,0.0")  + " ש""ח"
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Actual result:

[image]

Also try the Expression like this:

```
" " + Format(Fields!sumToAuthorityDiff.Value,"0,0.0")  + "ש""ח"
```

and still it came up same as above.

So how do i make the text append to the end of the numbers?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried just swapping them round in the expresdion?  `" ש""ח" + Format(Fields!sumToAuthorityDiff.Value,"0,0.0") ` ?

Comment: Yes. And it came up like this: ש"ח16,133.3

Comment: If i try like this: Format(Fields!sumToAuthorityDiff.Value,"0,0.0") + "ש""ח"
Then the result look good but with no space between the text and the number.